# Reordering an "dict" Object and shoveling multiple keys into an array of values (swap key-values in dictionary) | Ruby to Python

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary

This is my Ruby code. I want to convert this function to a Python 3 equivalent.

```
files = {
  'Input.txt' => 'Randy',
  'Code.py' => 'Stan',
  'Output.txt' => 'Randy'
}    

def group_by_owners(files)
  files.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), new_hash| (new_hash[value] ||= []) << key }
end

puts group_by_owners(files)
```

The Ruby result looks like this:

```
{"Randy" => ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan" => ["Code.py"]}
```

Python would be:

```
{"Randy": ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan": ["Code.py"]}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
def group_by_owners(files):
  new_dict = dict(zip(files.values(), (files.keys())))
  print(new_dict)
```

Then I was trying to append the keys to an array.

```
def group_by_owners(files):
  keys_array = []
  new_dict = dict(zip(files.values(), keys_array.append((files.keys()))))
```

but I don't think that will work inside of a zip method.

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn't a code translation service. And that output isn't Python.

Comment: Isn't the result more like `{"Randy": ["Input.txt", "Output.txt"], "Stan": ["Code.py"]}` ?

Comment: There is still no Python code in your question, so... *what* is what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, your mentioned data structure is known as dictionary ([**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) in terms of code) and is syntactically represented as:

```
files = {
   'Input.txt': 'Randy',
   'Code.py': 'Stan',
   'Output.txt': 'Randy'
}
```

In order to swap the key and values of your `dict`, you may use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict

swapped_dict = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in files.items():
    swapped_dict[value].append(key)
```

where `swapped_dict` is a `dict` object holding the value:

```
{
    'Randy': ['Output.txt', 'Input.txt'],
    'Stan': ['Code.py']
}
```

**Note:** Ruby maintains the order, but in Python version < 3.6, the `dict` objects are unordered in nature. However, [from Python version >= 3.6, `dict` objects are now ordered in nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6).

For Python versions < 3.6, we have [**`collections.OrderedDict`**](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which maintains the order in which keys are inserted. Here's an example to show the swapping of key/value pairs:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# for maintaining the order, your initial list 
# should also be of the type `OrderedDict`
old_dict = OrderedDict([('Input.txt', 'Randy'), ('Code.py', 'Stan'), ('Output.txt', 'Randy')])

for k, v in old_dict.items():
    new_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    # You may use `setdefault` on normal dictionaries too
```

which will return `dict` object as:

```
>>> new_dict
OrderedDict([('Randy', ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt']), ('Stan', ['Code.py'])])
```

It is just represented like this, you can access `new_dict` like a normal dictionary object.

Comment: Come on, you've had over a year to update to Python 3.6 :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann Still I mostly work on Python 2.7, and sometime on 3.4.5 due to old official projects (we haven't migrated them yet). After reading your comment, I explored a bit and updated the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: In Ruby insertion order is maintained.

Comment: @steenslag added an example of ordered dictionaries too

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thanks for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def group_by_owners(files: dict): -> dict
    res = {v: [] for v in files.values() }
    for k, v in files.items():
        res[v].append(k)
    return res
```

**Note:** in Python dicts are unordered (until 3.7 version).

Comment: Dicts will be ordered as of two weeks ago: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html This will become part of the Python 3.7 spec, and all conforming implementations of Python 3.7 must implement it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary version of `files` in Python:

```
files = {'Input.txt': 'Randy',
         'Code.py': 'Stan',
         'Output.txt' : 'Randy'}
```

`files.items()` returns:

`dict_items([('Input.txt', 'Randy'), ('Code.py', 'Stan'), ('Output.txt', 'Randy')])`

```
def group_by_owners(files):    
    result = dict() # empty dict

    for k, v in files.items(): 
        if v in result:
            result[v].append(k) # Append to list value if the key is in result
        else:
            result[v] = [k]  # Add key: value        

    return result


print(group_by_owners(files))
# {'Randy': ['Input.txt', 'Output.txt'], 'Stan': ['Code.py']}
```